# Need help identifying a connector so I can replace damaged keyboard USB cable

Tags: connector

Need help identifying this 5 pin female connector that attaches to my Logitech G810's PCB, standard USB 2.0 one end, then the 5pin female+ ground on other end. It looks very similar to a 4pin PWM fan connector. All help gratefully received.Pic of PCB side of connector in last pic. Thnx[image: cable]..

[image: connector]
[image: c2]

[image: c3]

[image: PCB connection]

[image: comp]

[image: comp1]

Comment: Welcome! What’s the pin-pin pitch?

Comment: You can cut the wires and leave a short section of the original wiring and connector, so you don't need to find the connector.

Comment: Looks like a Molex minimate.

Comment: Sorry guys I have limited electrical experience, dont know exact pin pitch, have added 2 pics showing comparison  with a 4 pin PWM fan. Pitch is smaller to accommodate extra pin but width identical but slightly shallower on height will try n dig out an engineering rules from my dads old toolboxes to get exact pin pitch and connector dimensions for you

Comment: Honestly, I would splice in a new USB type-A connector / cable and use the old white connector.  I would use an ohm meter to verify the 2 black wires were shorted together.  And I might verify that the shield  (screw down) wire was also shorted to the other 2 black wires. This because when you cut into an existing USB cable w/a type-A connector it will likely only have 4 wires.  One of each color, green, white, red and black.  You can also flip the PCB over to verify if the 2 pins associated with the black wire are shorted together.

Comment: Bring out a ruler, tape measure or caliper.

Comment: Wait, this is a gaming keyboard w/all kinds of LEDs?!  So, if you do go the route of splicing in a new USB type-A connector cable you might pay attention to the gauge of the red and black wires in the replacement cable.  Thin wires from cheap USB cables don't carry as much current as thicker red and black wires of more expensive USB cables.

Comment: very good pictures... add a picture that shows the white connector side by side with the USB connector ... that will help with determining dimensions

Answer (score 5):

That is a **JST PH 2.00 mm-pitch** 5-pin connector.

Comment: Aris - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be a source webpage link & added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) To remind yourself of the main site rules, please see the [tour] & [help]. Thanks.